# Automatically fill in the email address of the person that ticks a checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a table of data in Google Sheets. Several rows of data need to be validated by a superior. How would I add a checkbox for those rows, such that whoever ticks them as the verifier would have their email address automatically filled into the cell next to it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to accomplish what you *need* would be to insert a column for each verifier, and protect the columns so that only the pertinent person can tick checkboxes in "their" column. See [Protect a range or sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656#zippy=%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet).

To do what you *asked*, you need a script that runs on a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). However, in the general case, scripts that run in an trigger context cannot find the identity of the user at the keyboard. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()):

> *the user's **email address is not available** in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, **these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Workspace domain as the user**.*

In other words, if you are in a Google Workspace domain, you *can* discover the identity of the user at the keyboard and put their email address in a column. If you are using free @gmail.com accounts, you cannot.

It is best to ask users to authorize the script before running. That can be done with a custom menu item. See my [insertActiveUserEmailAddressInColumn_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/29026160?hl=en&msgid=29371236) script for sample code.

Comment: Nice alternative. Btw, I see many such links to your own posts. If you are the author of the script, It's a good idea to disclose it in your answer here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/promotion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427730

Comment: @TheMaster edited the answer.